# Integration over Levy Paths

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

In quantum mechanics, for a particle in a potential $V(x)$ we postulate that the propagator - which is the probability of transition between two points- is given by the Feynmann path integral:

$$K(x_b,t_b|x_a,t_a)=\int_{x_{t_a}=x_a}^{x_{t_b}=x_b}Dx(t)\exp\left\{-\frac{i}{h}\int_{t_a}^{t_b}dtV(x(t))\right\}$$

with measure of integration $$\begin{aligned}
\int_{x_i}^{x_f} \mathcal{D} x(\tau) \ldots=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \int d x_{1} \ldots d x_{N-1}\left(\frac{2 \pi i \hbar \varepsilon}{m}\right)^{-N / 2} \times \\  \prod_{j=1}^{N} \exp \left\{\frac{i m}{2 \hbar \varepsilon}\left(x_{j}-x_{j-1}\right)^{2}\right\} \ldots
\end{aligned} $$

I'm novice in measure theory and my understanding is that the measure in Feynmann integration is the measure induced by Brownian motion as a Wiener process : [Wiener measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WienerMeasure.html). Hence we say that it "corresponds to integration over all Brownian paths". Is this correct? Is there another reason-way to see why the above is an integral over brownian paths?

Now I am studying Laskin's Fractional Quantum Mechanics where the above expression is replaced by an "integral over Levy flights" or "the measure generated by the Levy flight-process". However I can't find any proof as to how this expression (found in the [original paper by Laskin](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.62.3135), as well as in [this one available in arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.5533.pdf) and his book "Fractional Quantum Mechanics"): $$\begin{aligned} K\left(x_{b} t_{b} | x_{a} t_{a}\right)=& \lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d x_{1} \ldots d x_{N-1} \frac{1}{(2 \pi \hbar)^{N}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d p_{1} \ldots d p_{N} \\ & \times \exp \left\{\frac{i}{\hbar} \sum_{j=1}^{N} p_{j}\left(x_{j}-x_{j-1}\right)\right\} \\ &  \times \exp \left\{-\frac{i}{\hbar} D_{\alpha} \varepsilon \sum_{j=1}^{N}\left|p_{j}\right|^{\alpha}-\frac{i}{\hbar} \varepsilon \sum_{j=1}^{N} V\left(x_{j}\right)\right\} \end{aligned} $$
corresponds to "an integral over Levy Paths". Additionaly Levy walks are not a Wiener process since the variance is infinite, so we don't have the same way of inducing a measure on continuous functions, so why and how is the above expression (without the term containing $V$) "a measure generated by Levy flights".

P.S. I'm not sure if this should be on physics-stack, but I think I'm more likely to find an answer here.

Comment: You don't have a measure on the space of all *continuous* functions, but you do have a measure on the [Skorokhod space of all cadlag functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g).  Intuitively, every stochastic process should induce a measure on any space of paths that the paths of the process lie in with probability 1.  (This is not literally true but it's good intuition to start with.)

Comment: Any intuition as to why the inyegration defined this way by Laskin corresponds to the one induced by the Levy process?